# Is there a way that I can open an SSIS package via command line?

Tags: command-line, ssis, remote-server

My situation is I need to remote into a server core (without desktop) and open an SSIS package to see how it is created. Is there a way that I can open the file (.dtsx) via command line?

I searched online, a lot of posts talking about how to execute the package via cmd, but I don't want to execute, I only need to open and view it, any ways that I can do?

Comment: What do you mean "open"? A `dtsx` file is an XML file so you can read and edit it with any text editor, or even `cat`. Even the smallest file is too big to display with `cat` in a single screen though.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'd like to open it by visual studio from that server via command line

Comment: The question is "Can I open/edit a package on a remote filesystem?" Can you access the server via a UNC path? aka `\\server\share\folder`

Comment: `to see how it is created` you can't do that by looking at the file. An SSIS file is essentially a serialized graph of objects stored as XML. The format is [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_data_portability/ms-dtsx/235600e9-0c13-4b5b-a388-aa3c65aec1dd) but nobody edits the XML file directly and few tools generate it. Almost everyone uses SSDT to edit the workflows and dataflows graphically

Comment: If you already know you need to use Visual Studio, you aren't using the command line. What's the actual question? And how would you use VS on Server Core? Is the real question how to access the file remotely? If the file is in a shared folder, open SSDT/VS and then open the file

Comment: @billinkc I think you are right, don't know about UNC path. But I can get the access to the server and I also know the file path of the package.